# Is it possible to give IP on the bracket settings for server?

Tags: aem, adobe-brackets

I am trying to set up Bracket with AEM. My server is running at http://192.168.56.101:4502/ Now on Bracket it seems to need localhost. In my hosts file, I have `192.168.56.101 docker` As a result I can not say 192.168.56.101 localhost. Is it possible to give IP on the bracket settings for server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently, brackets create these .brackets.json files

For my case, two such files were created. You can do a quick search for these files. Inside the file I have as below to make the changes needed

Remember by default AEM admin/admin are the username/password. Change to whatever you have for your own localserver if different.

```
{
    "sly.serverUrl": "http://192.168.56.101:4502",
    "sly.remoteUser": "admin",
    "sly.remoteUserPassword": "admin",
    "sly.autoSync": true,
    "sly.acceptSelfSignedCertificates": false
}
```